# Passing a function as a param using Redux with Hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, redux

**NOTE**: I am using React Navigation 5.x

What I'm trying to do is to navigate from a parent screen to a child screen. I would then enter details in the child screen. When I submit the details, I would like to take the details to update the state of my parent screen

I previously tried to `JSON.stringfy()` and then `JSON.parse()` the details, but that did not help me to update the state

I was previously following [this](https://heartbeat.fritz.ai/using-redux-with-react-hooks-in-a-react-native-app-cc410a77f3e2) tutorial but they using React Navigation 4.x

ParentScreen:

```
export default function Home({navigation}) {
    
  const auctions = useSelector(state => state)
  const dispatch = useDispatch()

  const addAuction = auction => dispatch(addauction(auction))
  const deleteAuction = id => dispatch(deleteauction(id))

  useEffect(() => {

    addAuction
  })

  
  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {auctions.length === 0 ? (
        
          <Text >You do not have any auctions</Text>
        
      ) : (
        <FlatList
          data={data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <List.Item
              title={item.auction.auctionTitle}
              description={item.auction.auctionValue}
              descriptionNumberOfLines={1}
              onPress={() => deleteAuction(item.id)} //Check
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.id.toString()}
        />
      )}
      <FAB
        style={styles.fab}
        small
        icon='plus'
        label='Add new auction'
        onPress={() =>
          navigation.navigate('Auctions', {
            auction: auctions
          })
        }
      />
    </View>
  </>
  );
}
```

ChildScreen:

```
export default function Auctions({route, navigation}) {
    
  const [auctionTitle, setAuctionTitle] = useState('')
  const [auctionValue, setAuctionValue] = useState('')


  function onSaveAuction() {
    

    navigation.navigate('Auction Details', {
      auctionTitle: auctionTitle,
      auctionValue: auctionValue
    })

  }
  
  return (
    <>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <IconButton
          icon='close'
          size={25}
          color='white'
          onPress={() => navigation.goBack()}
        />
        <TextInput
          label='Add Title Here'
          value={auctionTitle}
          mode='outlined'
          onChangeText={setAuctionTitle}
        />
        <TextInput
          label='Add Note Here'
          value={auctionValue}
          onChangeText={setAuctionValue}
          mode='flat'
          multiline={true}
          scrollEnabled={true}
          returnKeyType='done'
          blurOnSubmit={true}
        />
        <FAB
          style={styles.fab}
          small
          icon='check'
          disabled={auctionTitle == '' ? true : false}
          onPress={() => onSaveAuction()}
        />
      </View>
    </>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stick with that tutorial, it's mostly on Redux. Which you are still using in your current code.

The 'auctions' data is being stored in the Redux state which is correct since FlatLists play best that way. So react-navigation params won't change anything.

Your goal is going to be to dispatch an action that either updates or adds a new auction in your 'onSaveAuction' handler. Redux will update your parent screen automatically when your action is dispatched. Then use react-navigation to move your back to the parent screen.

I would start with a To-do list example, and get a better idea of how Redux stores data. Redux is going to store all your data for the most part and react-navigation is going to keep track of where you are. In general you will update Redux and then navigate.

Here's one from Redux docs but there are tons out there. Pretty close to what your currently doing.
https://redux.js.org/basics/example/